# Convert ArrayList<Object[]> to Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How, in Java, do I convert an ArrayList of arrays to a two-dimensional array?

Example:

```
ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String [] columns = {a few strings};


JTable table = new JTable(results.toArray(), columns);
```

I get the error that JTable(Object[], Object[]) is not defined.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`List<T>.toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) method should do the job.

For example:

```
List<String[]> list = ...
String[][] res = new String[list.size()][];
list.toArray(res);
```

or

```
List<String[]> list = ...
Object[][] res = new Object[list.size()][];
list.toArray(res);
```

If you use this overload rather than the `List<T>.toArray()` overload, you can choose the actual type of the array.  It takes one extra line of code, but if the array type is significant, this is the way to do it.

(The `List<T>.toArray()` overload gives you an array whose actual type is `Object[]` ... *irrespective* of the generic type of the list, or the actual type(s) of the list elements.)

Comment: I see.  I was using res = Object[] instead of Object[][].  Thanks!  (Yes, the code in the OP is a previous version.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! <3

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `array.toArray()` will do the trick.

Comment: @yodie - see my answer for a better solution.

Comment: @Stephen C -- done!  It just took a few seconds to comment and another three minutes to accept!