# Convert ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> to Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I would like to populate a JTable with the cnstructor like this :

```
new JTable(datas, columns);
```

so I need an `Object[]` for the columns and a `Object[][]` for the datas. 
The problem is when I try to get the datas.

In one of my method I work with an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` and I would like to cast it to an  `Object[][]`.

Here's a sample of my code :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> datas = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, JSObject> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    datas.add(entry.getValue().getValues()); // getValues returns an ArrayList<Object>
}

return new datas.toArray(); //  not seems to work
```

I saw in this question [Convert ArrayList<Object[]> to Object[][]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372439/convert-arraylistobject-to-object) some idea, but I'm not sure about the result.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you use `Object[][]` directly for `datas`?

Comment: Also, `return new datas.toArray();` is not a valid statement (`new` should probably be removed)

Comment: because I get params from another object where I prefere to use `ArrayList` but I try this solution, and let you know what comes from it... And yes the `new` had nothing to do here, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just change the type of `datas` to an `ArrayList<Object[]>`, and use `toArray()` each time you add an element:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> datas = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, JSObject> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    datas.add(entry.getValue().getValues().toArray());
}
return datas.toArray(new Object[][]{});
```

Comment: I have to add `(Object[][])` to cast the return statment but it seems to work, I test it and let you know

Comment: @Nobe4: True, used the other `toArray()` instead to prevent the need to cast.